# Hibernate Annotation Bidirectional relationship cascade delete with non null foreign key

Tags: hibernate, cascade, cascading-deletes, bidirectional, notnull

When performing a delete on an Order(the parent), hibernate is trying to cascade delete the children.  Instead of just deleting the children first, it is attempting to null out the foreign keys, then delete the parent, then delete the children.

Is there a way to change my configuration to allow the children to be deleted first, then the parent to be deleted?  Bypassing the step of nulling out the foreign key?

### Tables and relevant columns

**Order**

id - PK, int, not null

**OrderResult**

id - PK, int, not null
order_id - FK, int, not null

### Entity specification

**Order**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "CLOrderID")
public List<OrderResult> getOrderResults() {
    return orderResults;
}
```

**OrderResult**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CLOrderID", nullable = false)
public Order getOrder() {
    return order;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the optional attribute of your ManyToOne to false?

Comment: Yes, I just retried for good measure.  Same issue, "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CLOrderID'".

Comment: Have you found a fix for this @JohnHelfert ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that Cascade DELETE is set properly. That's why when you delete the User, the DELETE action is not cascaded, i.e, delete the OrderResult as well. It instead update the OrderResult by setting the reference value to NULL as Order has been deleted.

To fix it, change your `Order` class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="order")
public List<OrderResult> getOrderResults() {
    return orderResults;
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: This actually doesn't work, I attempted to set the cascade to all with  a mappedBy relationship and it still throws the constraint issue.